# Network Manager losing saved vpn passwords in Mint 17

Tags: security, vpn, networkmanager

my vpn is setup in the network manager, and the passwords are saved in there.

however, those passwords are disappearing, they will be there for several days, and then be gone.

what could be causing this? any advice would be appreciated. when i try to connect the network manager will ask for the passwords after days of use with those passwords already saved.

Comment: Not sure how Mint manages saved passwords and how that's integrated with NM, but have you tried hardcoding the password in the respective connection file located in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`? You would need `[vpn-secrets]` (new line) `password=xxxxxx`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem and it was caused by `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon`.

To be more precise:
After trying several things to prevent Linux Mint 17 from saving the passwords to my SSH keys I got frustrated and replaced `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon` with a symlink to `/bin/false`.

This caused NetworkManager to forget all my VPN passwords and made it impossible to save VPN passwords with NetworkManager.

Therefore I would investigate the gnome-keyring.
Note that gnome-keyring has some configuration files in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.

Comment: The passwords are only being stripped sometimes, and only under certain conditions. This is not a bug I believe but a tool. I live in a repressive country. We all need vpns here just to get basic webpages like email, and then the government tries to deny VPN service.
The behavior never happens outside this country. The behavior is that I will have trouble to connect to VPN, and then suddenly the passwords are gone. 
Recently the behavior changed, the password was replaced, so then the pass looks to be there but its still invalid secrets.